# Determine from function when an event stops with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Simplified scenario:

- I have a click event on a button
- Inside the event I call a function X
- Function X returns a value
- Click event changes DOM using received data (actually renders a jQuery Template)

SAMPLE CODE:

```
$("button").click(function()
{
    var response = FunctionX();

    doTemplateRendering(response); //(*)
});

function FunctionX()
{
    //some code

    return some_value;

    //The click event has finished, so now make a little adjust to the generated dom (*)
}
```

The questions are:

- Do I have a way to determine when the click stops form `FunctionX()`?
- Or is there a way that `doTemplateRendering()` triggers something that I can capture from `FunctionX()` so it doesn't matter if I return a value, because at some point I'm going to be able to execute the extra code that I need

The reason behind this is that this is part of a framework and I can't change the click event.

Comment: Your questions are very unclear, particularly the first one. What do you mean *"...when the click stops form `FunctionX`?"*??

Comment: Are you looking for when the mouse button is released? We have `mouseup` for that.

Comment: Does the `doTemplateRendering()` function have a callback? Once `Functionx` has returned a value then it can't do anything else.

Comment: What do you mean by: determine when the click stops form FunctionX()? Maybe you are trying to say that functionX() will remove the click() method from $("button")? in other words do you mean that functionX() will not allow $("button")to continue working on click? Try to edit your question and make it more clear.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know is confusing. I'm trying to do some extra processing after an event that I can't change

Comment: @Matías: I don't mean the concept. I mean I don't know what you mean by the words *"...when the click stops form FunctionX?"* Define "stop" and "form" in that sentence, and we *might* be able to help. Do you mean, "From within the code in `FunctionX`, how can I tell when the `click` event handler that called it exits?"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return a value from a function and then do further processing within the same function. But you can schedule some code to run later using `setTimeout()`:

```
function FunctionX()
{
    //some code    

    setTimeout(function() {
        //The click event has finished, so now make a little adjust to the generated dom (*)
    }, 5);

    return some_value;
}
```

JS is single-threaded (if we ignore web-workers), so the function you pass to timeout won't be executed until after the click event finishes.

Alternatively, you can bind a second click handler to the same button and do your extra processing there - jQuery guarantees that event handlers (for the same event and element) will be run in the order that they're bound.

Comment: I considered that. The thing is: can I have a possible conflict if the settimeout is scheduled for 2 seconds and the rendering takes 3?

Comment: Assuming the rendering is done with entirely synchronous code then no, you won't have a problem, the timeout won't be executed until after the current code finishes executing no matter how long it takes. If the rendering has an async component (e.g., if it does some sort of animation) then you probably can't tell when it is finished unless it allows you to provide a callback function.

Comment: sounds promising. I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works for you, but couldn't you use a callback function that you pass to FunctionX?

```
$("button").click(function()
{
    var fn = funcion(){response){
         doTemplateRendering(response);
    }
    FunctionX(fn);

});

function FunctionX(fn)
{
    //some code

    fn(some_value);

    //The click event has finished, so now make a little adjust to the generated dom (*)
}
```